# Calculating Next Working Date in SQL

Tags: sql

I am writing an SSRS report for OTRS tickets and my challenge is as follows. I have to determine if the SLA of a ticket falls on the same date as when the ticket was opened. my working week is Monday to Friday excluding holidays. The working hours in a day are from 09:00 to 17:00 (8 hours in total.) some priority tickets have a 2 hour resolution time and some non essential tickets have 5 days resolution time. If a priority ticket is opened at 16:55 on a Friday and the following Monday is a holiday , the resolution date should be on Tuesday 10:55 (in other words the ticket SLA should fall on the next working day within the working hours)

My SLA time is stored in an ticket_SLA table in minutes i.e. (2hrs = 120 minutes or 5 days = 2400 minutes). The Calculation of the 5 days is as follows:

2400 minutes divided by 60 minutes to get hours, divided  by 8 to get the number of days(there is 8 hours in a working day)

2400/60/8 = 5 days.

Having determined this I have to go on further and determine if the ticket is within SLA or not. if not I show the ticket in a different color on the report.

The available fields that i should work off are as follows:

**ticket table:**

```
Create_time datetime, ticket_sla_id int, tn long,
```

**sla table:**

```
sla_Id int, solution_time int (number of minutes)
```

**holidays table:**

```
holiday_name varchar, holiday_date, holiday_iD
```

any suggestions of How I could approach this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? Firebird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TSQL, check out my solution on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/696a3/2/0).
If you use another DBMS you should be able to transform sql to your syntax.

Solution provided will return a deadline for each ticket.
In the first CTE, you have to define min start- and max enddate.
Hope that helps!

Be aware of setting for datefirst ( see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174420.aspx) )

**@updated**: modified fiddle-demo

Comment: I See where you are going with this, however I have time constraints, my day is 8 hours long. ie if my sla is 24 hours that means I have 3 working days. If a ticket was logged at 10:00 AM on Tue 18 2012 and has an sla of 2400 minutes(5 days), taking into account 1. the weekend (Saturday and Sunday) 2. the xmas holiday on 25/12/2012 and on 26/12/2012 3. each day ends at 17:00

Comment: 25th and 26th of december haven't been regarded, because those days were not included in holiday-table. Anyway, you were right that i have missed to split sla into 8-hour-intervals. i've added this. see updated fiddle-demo in answer, please.